# How to capture "$?" before tee smashes it?

Tags: bash, tee, exit-status

I've got a test script that repeatedly builds a library under different configurations. It also `tee's` the output for postmortem failures:

```
$MAKE" static dynamic cryptest.exe 2>&1 | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: failed to make cryptest.exe" | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
fi
```

The script is not working as intended because the test is capturing `tee's` return code, and not `make's` return code.

I looked at the man pages for `tee(1)`, but I don't see an option to have it restore a return code.

How can I capture the return code from make before `tee` smashes it?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. I don't really understand the significance of the braces in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`. Would I simply use `if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne "0" ]; then ...`? Or do I need something else within the script? (My apologies; I'm a C/C++/Objective C guy).

Comment: since `PIPESTATUS` takes you into `bash` land, you may as well use a bash arithmetic expression, so `if (( PIPESTATUS[0] ))` is equivalent to `if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne "0" ]`